# remove css hover opacity after item clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to remove a css opacity transition rule I have when you hover over an image. How can I remove this from happening after an item is clicked.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XYZZx/29/)
HTML

```
<ul id="grid">   
  <li><div class="title"></div><a href="#"class="zoom"><img src="1.jpg"><span></span></a></li>
  <li><div class="title"></div><a href="#" class="zoom" ><img src="2.jpg"><span></span></a></li>
  <li><div class="title"></div><a href="#" class="zoom"><img src="3.jpg"><span></span></a></li>
  <li><div class="title"></div><a href="#" class="zoom"><img src="4.jpg"><span></span></a></li>
  <li><div class="title"></div><a href="#" class="zoom"><img src="5.jpg"><span></span></a></li>
  <li><div class="title"></div><a href="#" class="zoom"><img src="6.jpg"><span></span></a></li>
  <li><div class="title"></div><a href="#" class="zoom"><img src="7.jpg"><span></span></a></li>
  <li><div class="title"></div><a href="#" class="zoom"><img src="8.jpg"><span></span></a></li>
  <li><div class="title"></div><a href="#" class="zoom" ><img src="9.jpg"><span></span></a></li>
 </ul>
  <div id="hidden"></div>
```

The CSS I'm tring to remove after a mouse click

```
 #grid li a:hover img {
   -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in;
   -moz-transition: opactiy .2s ease-in;
   -ms-transition: opacity .2s ease-in;
   -o-transition: opacity .2s ease-in;
   transition: opacity .2s ease-in;
   opacity: 1;
    }

 #grid:hover li {
   -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in;
   -moz-transition: opactiy .2s ease-in;
   -ms-transition: opacity .2s ease-in;
   -o-transition: opacity .2s ease-in;
   transition: opacity .2s ease-in;
   zoom: 1;
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 0.3;
   }
```

Would I do something like (see below) in jquery?

```
$(this).removeClass('grid');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
<a class="image" href="#image">
    <img src="image.png" id="image" />
</a>
```

And in the css:

```
a.image img:target
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a .click() jQuery function:

```
$(".grid").click(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('grid')
});
```

Also, change your CSS style to Class instead of ID. Right now its `#grid`. You'll need `.grid` for it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the loads of help I've put together a jsfiddle because I can see to get it working [link](http://jsfiddle.net/XYZZx/28)

Comment: If this is your answer, or somewhat matches you answer, please mark this question with a tick... its below the voting points arrow.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `ID` attribute, not `class`.

Change `<ul id="grid">` to `<ul class="grid">`

And `#grid` whenrever it's used in your CSS to `.grid`.

Then your jQuery

```
$(this).removeClass('grid');
```

Should work fine :)

Comment: Thanks a million for the #grid to .grid help. for some reason I can get $(this).removeClass('grid'); to remove the class or other classes I've tried

Comment: I noticed in your jsFiddle you're using `removeClass('.grid')`. Change it to `removeClass('grid')` ;). It already knows you want to remove the class so you don't need the `.` as a class selector.

Comment: There is also another thing - you're trying to remove 'grid' from something that isn't 'grid'. Look at this, it's removing the class successfully now: http://jsfiddle.net/XYZZx/32/

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
    $( this ).removeAttr( 'id' );
```

or `<ul id="grid">` to `<ul class="grid">`